# Spinner moves down once receives items

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple layout, below is a relevant fragment. It looks exactly as I want it to - as long as the spinner is empty. Once I add items to it (in runtime) - it jumps like half its height down.
Why?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl"
                        style="@style/Label.Plain"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner"
                        style="@style/Spinner"
                        android:background="#ff0000"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is "Spinner" style:

```
<style name="Spinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/button_height</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/spinner_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/button</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
   </style>
```

Comment: sorry dude, i tried with ur layout and style.. its working fine.. i cant reproduce d issue.. pls check ur fragment what happens while u addin values..

Comment: @baya: thank you very much for testing! Weird thing is the issue definitely appeared when I was tinkering with that fragment of layout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't understand why, but the problem disappeared as soon as I set spinner's padding to 0dp instead of 2dp specified by the style.